# Why using multiversioned views?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I don't see the reason why multiversioned views exist.

It's not possible to use joins like in normal views. And editing versions is possible by directly using the feature class itself. So when am I supposed to use them?

---

So if I understand:

[image]

When I query the feature class, I query the compressed DB. And ***the only*** way to access data in the versions, is using mv views.
Am I wrong?

Comment: The help seems to make a few suggestions http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html

Comment: I read the documentation but I didn't find (or understand) the "WHY" of mv views. What I understood is that a mv view is a simple view (no joins allowed) used to edit a version of the feature class, if this one isn't part of a geodatabase functionality (NA, dataset, ...). Feature class versions can be edited without mv views. So what's the particularity of mv  views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "multiversion" name is somewhat misleading.

Every versioned feature class has three tables in the database:

- The business/base table (this is the table that you could query directly)
- The additions table (something like A100)
- The deletes table (something like D100)

Any changes in the current version will be in the 'A' table and deletions in the 'D' table. Those changes stay in those tables until the database is compressed and they are moved to 'state 0.'

The multiversion view selects all of the records for the current version, merging the changes from all 3 tables. You could simply select data from the business table, but if your database hasn't been compressed lately, you could be missing changes (even if they've been posted).

To put it simply, you need to use multiversion views if you are querying data that is being edited frequently between database compressions.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/What_are_multiversioned_views/0093000015nt000000/),

> Multiversioned views incorporate database views, stored procedures,
>   triggers, and functions to access a specified version of data in a
>   geodatabase table using Structured Query Language (SQL).

Not everyone has a need to use them.  When you encounter a situation that
can only be resolved by accessing versioned data via SQL (outside of Desktop),
then you may better understand why they exist.

Comment: Can you give me a situation that exclusively needs mv views?
Stored procedures and triggers can be mv views? The SDE command to create the mv view is quite simple and doesn't allow doing anything special => so I understand that a mv view is a simple view.